# WPF TextBox StringFormat not working with PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, string-formatting

I have a problem. I need to have **double formatted values** in all TextBoxes.

When you type something into this, after lost focus it will be formatted.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ABC, StringFormat='{}{0:N}'}"  />
```

Problem arises when you add this UpdateSourceTrigger with propertychanged. Then it will never be formatted.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ABC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='{}{0:N}'}"  />
```

Why is that? Is there any way how to solve that? (in XAML preferably)

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200464/problem-with-updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-and-stringformat-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextBox x:Name="test" Text="{Binding MyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit,StringFormat='{}{0:N}'}" TextChanged="test_TextChanged" Width="100" Height="30" />


 private void test_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression exp = test.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        exp.UpdateSource(); 
    }
```